# Foreign key vs intermediate tables

Tags: sql, model, relational-database

This is a **very basic question** and I apologize for that, but I didn't find any resource to answer this question.

I see these diagrams everywhere and I am having a hard time trying to understand **why they use an intermediate table to relate State and Country instead of just adding a foreign key in State table pointing to Country table**.

Is it because some RDMS don't allow foreign keys? Is it because the name of the state can be in many countries?

[image]

Source: [Database Design and Naming Conventions](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/232457/Database-Design-and-Naming-Conventions)

Answer (score 4):

This type of table is called a junction table and is used to represent many-to-many relationships.  As far as I know, all states are within a single country, so there is no need to have a junction table.  A state could simple have a `country_id` column.  You are correct.

You might think the same of the "county" and "city" entities.  At least in the United States, this is not strictly true (unless you follow the Census Bureau definitions).  Some cities do span multiple counties.

As a write this, I am in New York County (more commonly known as "Manhattan"), which is part of New York City.  New York City actually comprises five counties.  Other cities also span counties, such as Chicago (Cook and DuPage counties), Atlanta (Fulton and Dekalb), and many other (listed on this [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._municipalities_in_multiple_counties) page).  New York City of course "wins", spanning five, more than any other ;)

Comment: I understand, but what if there are two New York states in different countries, could this model address that kind of problems? (Though I don't see how, having a unique id for both states should be enough..)

Comment: @HernanMartinDemczuk . . . It is doubtful that they would be the same political entity.  I'm sure there are "states"/"provinces" that have the same name in different countries.  However, they are different states/provinces.  The page referenced in Wikipedia is not about Springfield, MO and Springfield, MA having the same name.  It is single political entities that cross borders.

Answer (score 1):

This design makes no sense to me.

The intermediate tables are used for many-to-many relationships.  For example, an academic database might have Student and Course tables, with a Student_Course (or Transcript) in between.  A Student can take many Courses, and a Course can have many Students.

It this case a State can only belong to one Country, so the design seems silly.

A foreign key is the way to express a one-to-many relationship, with the key added to the many child to point to its single parent.